# LED bulbs increasing measured AC line voltage?

Tags: ac, multimeter

I was troubleshooting an LED light flickering issue on a ceiling fan. Note the house is a partial knob and tube conversion with no grounds, switched neutrals etc.

First I measured the voltage at the fan with the LED bulbs removed and the meter reads a perfect 120VAC. With LED bulbs installed and illuminated (flickering) the measured voltage ranges from 150VAC to 200VAC. I am using a Fluke111 meter.

To make things even stranger. When I wire the LED assembly to a pigtail and plug it into an outlet, the voltage reads a perfect 120VAC with no flickering.

So it is something wrong with the house wiring, but not sure what, and not sure how it could boost the voltage or fool the meter. Any insight would be helpful, thanks!

[image]

Comment: "the house is a partial knob and tube conversion" - what does that mean?

Comment: Sounds like the rectifer and constant current source inside the LED bulbs is putting something back onto the grid. Assuming the bulbs which you are fitting confrom fully to whatever relevant standard is required wherever you are located, then the wiring is seriously faulty and my adivce would be to get someone in who knows the regulations to do a full re-wire of at least the lighting and take a look at the rest of it.

Comment: @Finbarr, that means the house is old, very old.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knob-and-tube_wiring with some circuits being rewired using modern romex type wire.

Comment: Is the circuit in question on a dimmer?  Also, do you have any illuminated light switches?  Any 220V appliances? Try unplugging those.

Comment: @Aaron No dimmer or illuminated switches. The only system components I'm aware of is an old 20 amp breaker and low quality wiring. Possibly a bad connection creating resistance when the line is loaded. The ceiling fan was fully removed. Doesn't make sense so I will need to take my troubleshooting to the attic. Just curious if anyone had seen an issue like this before. Out of curiosity I might wire in an isolation transformer to see if the nasty waveform is just tricking the meter.

Comment: @Puffafish, yeah if the meter is telling the truth the LEDs must be boosting the voltage. I guess there must also be some sort of high resistance in the line to permit the voltage to be higher than the grid. Just a troubleshooting oddity I have never run into.

Comment: Usually when you have a higher than normal voltage, it's due to a loose/open neutral then when  a 220VAC appliance/oven/water heater turns on the imbalance causes high voltage to show up on other circuits.  This is what causes most surge protectors to catch on fire.

Comment: @Aaron, Interesting. I don't think any 220 appliances were on, but I will turn off all those breakers and test. Thanks!